# When close and reopen app saved data in sharedpreferences not showing?

Tags: java, android

I am saving data in android by using sharedpreferences in android.

I am able to save data sucessfully, but i don't know if close app and reopen saved data is not displaying.

My code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText;
Button button;
Button button1;
TextView text;
public static final String mypreference = "MY_PREFS_NAME";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
            editor.putString("mn",editText.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String ap = prefs.getString("mn","");
            text.setText(ap);




        }

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by you are not sure if it's saved? How do you test it?

Comment: remove unnecessary details change `i` to `I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this inside onClick

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
String ap = prefs.getString("mn","");
text.setText(ap);
```

So it will not do it automatically onLoad the next time. If you want to do that, you might move these lines in your `onCreate` method outside the clickListener implementation as shown below.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
 String ap = prefs.getString("mn","");
 text.setText(ap);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString("mn",editText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ap = prefs.getString("mn","");
        text.setText(ap);

    }

});
```